# '最终有个交代‘, '交代’ meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The sentence comes to my mind is

> at least, in the end, I can say that I tried everything I could.

Is there a corresponding expression for ‘交代’ here?

Comment: "to make up for sth,"

Answer (score 7):

「交代 」

1. (v)  to answer to  / to explain / to report ;
2. (n)  explanation / justification

Example:

向民眾**交代** (**answer to** the people / **explain** to the people)

給民眾一個**交代** (give people an **explanation**)

~

```
最終有個**交代** meaning
```

It means " At the end, there will be an **explanation**"

More example:

怎樣向皇上**交代** ( how to explain / report it to the emperor?)

你可獻上我的頭顱作為**交代** ( you can offer my head as your **report**)

~

**Additional Note:**

交代 mainly means "explain" or "explanation", and by extension, it also carries meanings of "report" and "instruction"

- If you explain how you've carried out a task to your boss - that would be "giving a report".
- If you explain how to carry out a task to your son - that would be "giving an instruction".

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought, 最终有了一个交代 means "I finally found an/the answer"

Now I'd like to know what 交代 really means and how to translate it.

你快死了。
你让我照顾你的孩子。
我把他抚养成人。
我最终对你有了一个交代。

I have done your bidding, but what is 有个交代？？

Looks like the other side of "I am in your debt", ie "you are in my debt".

Apparently there is a sense of something which takes a long time to 交代.

Edit: Got this comment from italki, seems to make sense:

> In traditional Chinese culture, people believe that there is an
>   afterlife. But people are not able to move on to the afterlife if they
>   have unfinished last wishes. Their souls are still entangled in this
>   world. If "有个交代” is related to finished last will, in a way it means
>   "let go".

So I think I can translate 我最终对你有了一个交代。 as "I have finally achieved closure for you."

Comment: cf. bkrs 2) сдавать (выполнять) задание I  accomplished my mission (task)

Comment: Wouldn't that be something like: 我完成了我的任务? I can't see how 有个交代 achieves that sense of meaning.

Comment: seems to agree more or less with above "I have done your bidding", anyhow where does this come from except the last line?

Comment: Sorry, where does what come from? If you mean the little Chinese text, I asked a friend to write a text to illustrate the use of 最终有个交代， which she did, but I can't see how to translate the last part successfully. Maybe I'm stuck on the idea of 'having something' 有个。 Can't see what I 'have.'

Comment: "this" refers to "I have done your bidding"

Comment: 交代 mainly means " explanation" and  by extension, it also carries a meaning of "instruction" as in 交代後事 ( explain to / instruct someone else to carry out one's will)  -- if you must use 交代 in a context of  "done someone's bidding" the sentence would be " 我最终完成了你交代的事" ( I finally accomplished the thing you instructed)

Comment: 交代後事 ( to instruct someone else to carry out one's will)  | 後事的交代 ( the instruction of how to carry out one's will) | 我最终完成了你交代的事 ( I finally carried out the thing you instructed) | 我最终完成了你的交代 ( I finally carried out your instruction)

Comment: I think you are ignoring the spiritual-cultural undertones. No one was instructed. "感觉英语也许没有这样的文化"

Comment: Believe me, 交代的事 means "give instruction to the people who will carry out your will"--  alone with other things, I will tell my sister to bury me in my cycling outfit.

Comment: “有个交代 is a very Chinese and has no equivalent meaning in English. I have checked many bilingual sentences with 有个交代, and find that people translate it in different ways according to the situation. “ ““完成了你最后的愿意”，不一定就是给他了一个交代。“

Comment: 交代 means  "to explain (v)" or "explanation (n)", if you give an explanation to your boss, that would be a "report"; if you explain to your son what to do after you're dead, that would be an "instruction"

Comment: I think we may have to agree to disagree. If it just means instruction, I will translate: '我最终对你有了一个交代。' 'I finally had for you an instruction.' I do not think that catches the meaning at all. Consider The Mad Hatter "A word may mean anything I want it to mean."

Comment: @Gangosa I think it works like this: because it means an explanation/briefing/telling (of) it can also be extended to mean a justification (for oneself) or an accounting (for ones self). So because the person has finally accomplished what they were supposed to have done, they say 我最终对你有了一个交代。I finally have accounted for ..... Something like that

Comment: Well, we can bend these meanings until they fit our preconceptions. If you have 'finally accounted'  or 'justified yourself', in the eyes of God or man, for something, you have finished and that chapter (of your life) is closed. That is 'get closure'.